# Install a Service Worker to Angular 4 App - no Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, service-worker, angular-service-worker

My current situation is that I support an app which pre-dates Angular CLI becoming the de-facto standard. It's supported via SystemJS and not WebPack among other things.

I'd like to install a Service Worker but the abundance of documentation, blogs, etc. recite from an audience using Angular CLI. Does anyone have a solution/step-by-step guide for installing a service worker on an Angular App sans CLI?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This seems like a valid question. Why is it being downvoted?

Comment: Thanks for your support @DeborahK - I really enjoy all of your Pluralsight tutorials.

Comment: Cory has a nice article here: https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers He updated it to Angular 6 ... but may have the older version of the article/code somewhere if you reach out to him.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/ Workbox is the latest Service Worker Library from Google. I actually use this on my Angular CLI projects and non Angular projects (React, Jekyll, ect...) because it works well with pretty much anything and has a really robust feature set. Its completely generic, you can generate a service worker with Workbox via CLI commands, NodeJS build script or a Webpack plugin.